# How to display DataGrid inside DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I want to add a single row `DataGrid` inside another `DataGrid`s row details template.

This is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,100,10,96" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding }" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" CellEditEnding="onCellEditEnding"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  >

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="No" Binding= "{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Barcode" Binding= "{Binding Path=Barcode, Mode=TwoWay}"  />

        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Item" Binding= "{Binding Path=Item, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Qty" Binding= "{Binding Path=Qty, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Mrp" Binding= "{Binding Path=Mrp, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Discount" Binding= "{Binding Path=Discount, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Cgst" Binding= "{Binding Path=Cgst, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Sgst" Binding= "{Binding Path=Sgst, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Amount" Binding= "{Binding Path=Amount, Mode=OneWay ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Salesman" Binding= "{Binding Path=Salesman, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="X" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid x:Name="RowDetailsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Details}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding CgstDetails}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding SgstDetails}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding DiscountDetails}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                
            </DataGrid> 
            
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

This is (roughly) my code-behind:

```
ObservableCollection<TableData> tableData = new ObservableCollection<TableData>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGrid.DataContext = tableData;
    
}

public class TableData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int No { get; set; }

  
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string CgstDetails { get; set; }

    public string SgstDetails { get; set; }
    public string DiscountDetails { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    private double qty;
    public double Qty {
        get { return qty; }
        set
        {
            qty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Qty");
            
        }
    }
    public double Mrp { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }
    public double Cgst { get; set; }
    public double Sgst { get; set; }
    private double amount; // field

    public double Amount
    {
        get { return amount; }
        set { 
            amount = (Qty * Mrp) + ((Cgst / 100) * (Mrp * Qty)) + ((Sgst / 100) * (Mrp * Qty));
            OnPropertyChanged("Amount");
        }
    }

    public int Salesman { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        
        
    }

    public bool RowAdded{ get; set; }
}

private void onCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    var rowFetched = new TableData()
    {
        Id = currentRowIndex + 1,
        No = currentRowIndex + 1,
        Barcode = item.Barcode,
        Qty = item.Qty,
        Mrp = item.Mrp,
        Item = item.Item,
        Discount = item.Discount,
        Cgst = item.Cgst,
        Sgst = item.Cgst,
        Amount = item.Amount,
        Salesman = item.Salesman,
        Details = item.Details,
        DiscountDetails = item.DiscountDetails,
        CgstDetails = item.CgstDetails,
        SgstDetails = item.SgstDetails,
        RowAdded = true
    };
    
    tableData.Insert(currentRowIndex, rowFetched);
}
```

This is not working. Instead of a `DataGrid` I have just put a `TextBlock` inside  `WrapPanel` (see the code below) and the data-binding is working perfectly and the data is shown in the row details, but I want it to be a row (`DataGrid`) instead of a `WrapPanel`.

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Background="LightGray">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="355" Padding="40 0 0 0" >
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding Details}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="71">
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding CgstDetails}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Width="71">
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding SgstDetails}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Width="71">
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding DiscountDetails}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Width="188">
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </WrapPanel> 
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

If anyone could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that it is a good idea to put a nested `DataGrid` into the row details template just to display a single row, but if that is your only option, you can do it as follows.

A `DataGrid` expects an [`ItemsSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=net-5.0) of a collection type, more specifically an `IEnumerable`. What you tried to do is bind properties on the `DataContext` itself directly, which does not work. There are at least two options that you have to make it work, both of which essentially provide a collection of a single item as `ItemsSource` to the nested `DataGrid`.

- Create a value converter that wraps your `TableData` item in a collection (here an array).

  ```
  public class ItemToCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
  {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
        return value is null ? null : new[] { value };
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
     }
  }
  ```

  Create an instance of the converter in XAML (e.g. in your `DataGrid.Resources`) and simply bind the data context using the converter to the `ItemsSource` of the nested `DataGrid`. This way, your `TableData` item gets wrapped in a collection and is treated as a single item collection, so the column bindings will work correctly.

  ```
  <DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,100,10,96" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" CellEditEnding="onCellEditEnding"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  >
      <DataGrid.Resources>
         <local:ItemToCollectionConverter x:Key="ItemToCollectionConverter"/>
      </DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="No" Binding= "{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Barcode" Binding= "{Binding Path=Barcode, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Item" Binding= "{Binding Path=Item, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Qty" Binding= "{Binding Path=Qty, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Mrp" Binding= "{Binding Path=Mrp, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Discount" Binding= "{Binding Path=Discount, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Cgst" Binding= "{Binding Path=Cgst, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Sgst" Binding= "{Binding Path=Sgst, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Amount" Binding= "{Binding Path=Amount, Mode=OneWay ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Header="Salesman" Binding= "{Binding Path=Salesman, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <Button Content="X" Click="Button_Click"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <DataGrid x:Name="RowDetailsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItemToCollectionConverter}}">
                  <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Details}"  />
                      <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding CgstDetails}"  />
                      <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding SgstDetails}"  />
                      <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding DiscountDetails}"/>
                  </DataGrid.Columns>
              </DataGrid>
          </DataTemplate>
      </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
  </DataGrid>
  ```
- Expose a collection property from your `TableData` type that contains a single item of a sub type or helper type that only contains the details properties.

  ```
  public class TableDetailsData
  {
     public string Details { get; set; }
     public string CgstDetails { get; set; }
     public string SgstDetails { get; set; }
     public string DiscountDetails { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  ```
  public class TableData : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     private TableDetailsData _detailsData;
     public TableDetailsData DetailsData
     {
        get => _detailsData;
        set
        {
           _detailsData = value;
           DetailsDataCollection = new List<TableDetailsData> { _detailsData };
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DetailsDataCollection));
        }
     }

     public IEnumerable<TableDetailsData> DetailsDataCollection { get; private set; }

     // ...other code.
  }
  ```

  The `DetailsDataCollection` is always updated when the `DetailsData` changes. Whether you create the collection like this and expose the `DetailsData` as object or as properties is up to you, there are many possibilities and this is only to get an idea what to do. Now you can bind this collection as `ItemsSource` in the nested `DataGrid`.

  ```
  <DataGrid x:Name="RowDetailsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsDataCollection}" CanUserAddRows="False">
  ```

Personally, I prefer the value converter solution as you do not have to expose a redundant collection property and pollute your code, as it is not a pretty clean solution. I would recommend you to create a proper details type and think about a better way to represent the data than a single row `DataGrid`, which seems out of place and does not provide a good user experience in this scenario.